# MVC WebAPI Help layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

Need some help with customizing the layout of WebAPI help pages that are auto generated.

I want to replace the @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SampleResponses, "Samples")

with Jquery UI tabs but can't seem to get it to work.

has anybody else achieved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, needed to create a new custom display template for this which uses JQuery UI tabs. Code as follows

```
<div id="resp-tabs">
    <ul>
        @{
            int count = 1;
            foreach (var mediaType in mediaTypes)
            {
                <li><a href="#resp-tab-@count">@mediaType</a></li>
                count++;
            }
        }
    </ul>

    @{
        count = 1;
        foreach (var mediaType in mediaTypes)
        {
            <div id="resp-tab-@count">
                @{
            var sample = samples[mediaType];
            if (sample == null)
            {
                <p>Sample not available.</p>
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(s => sample)
                ;
            }
                }
            </div>
            count++;
        }
    }
</div>
```